# Entity updated in a controlled not updated in a Job

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, playframework

Hi I'm having a problem with my project. I have a background job
running which updates one entity. The problem is that if I update
another entity from a controller the first one doesn't react to the
updated entity. But if I try to access from a controller the second
entity I can see that it was updated,

Here's the code:
Second entity 
package models;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import play.db.jpa.Model;
@Entity
public class GameMap extends Model {
    static int convPx=16;   //converts game pixels in the map rap.
    int[][] array;
    public GameMap(int[][] array) {
        this.array=array;
    }

    public boolean isSolid(int x,int y){
        try{
        if (array[y][x]==0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return true;
        }
    }
    public String collides(GameObject object){      //TODO fix if it collides top and left scenario
        if(isSolid((object.x+object.width/2)/convPx,object.y/convPx))
            return "top";
        if(isSolid((object.x+object.width/2)/convPx,(object.y+object.height)/
convPx))
            return "bottom";
        if(isSolid((object.x)/convPx,(object.y+object.height/2)/convPx))
            return "left";
        if(isSolid((object.x+object.width)/convPx,(object.y+object.height/2)/
convPx))
            return "right";
        else
            return "false";
    }

    public void addPoint(int x, int y, int what) {
        array[x/convPx][y/convPx]=what;
        this.save();
    }
}
```

I update it calling the appPoint() method from this controller

```
public static void addMapPoint(int x, int y){
            GameMap map =(GameMap) GameMap.findAll().iterator().next();
            map.addPoint(x, y, 1);

    }
```

This is the job that doesn't get updated

package controllers;

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import models.Ball;
import models.GameMap;
import play.jobs.Job;

public class BallJob extends Job {
    public void doJob() {
        List<Ball> balls;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Ball(40,40,4,4,10,10).save();
        int[][] mapArr = {

{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},

{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
        };
        GameMap m= new GameMap(mapArr);
        m.save();
        Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true){
        try {
            if(25-System.currentTimeMillis()+time>0){
                Thread.sleep(25-System.currentTimeMillis()+time);
            }
                time =System.currentTimeMillis();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        balls = Ball.findAll();
/***************************************************************
****************************************************************
* This map doesn't change
****************************************************************
***************************************************************/
        GameMap map = (GameMap) GameMap.findAll().iterator().next();

        for (Iterator iterator = balls.iterator();
iterator.hasNext();) {
            Ball ball = (Ball) iterator.next();
            ball.applyForces();
            if(ball.collides(map)){
            ball.applyForces();
            }

        }
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA doesn't propagate changes from the database to the existing entities into persistence context. I guess you need to refresh it:

```
map.refresh();
```

Comment: This works, but I can't understand why. with this line :GameMap map = (GameMap) GameMap.findAll().iterator().next();  I should get a new entity from the database, why should I need to update it manually?

Comment: @MaurizioPz: I'm not sure how Play Framework manages this, but from basic JPA understanding, calls of `findAll()` method happen inside the same persistence context, therefore loaded entities are cached by the context, and subsequent calls return cached instances.